# Query Results from Two Different Tables

Tags: sql, select, join

I'm trying to write a query to produce a dataset from two or more tables, and I'm having trouble writing the query.  I apologize in advanced my lack of knowledge in SQL.

Table 1 consists of basic customer account info and Table 2 consists of customer contract details where one customer account can have multiple contracts, both inactive and active

Table 1 and Table 2 can be joined with the values contained under a column named acct_id.

I would like the query to show only acct_ids where account status (acct_status) is "active" from Table 1, and that do not have an "active" contract from Table 2.

The problem is that in Table 2, there are more than one contract associated to an acct_id and are in different statuses.

If my where clause just focuses on the contract status values from table 2, my dataset won't be accurate.  It will only return acct_ids that have contracts with those values.

for example:

```
acct_iD 123 has 6 contracts: 1 active contract, 4 cancelled contracts, 1 cancel in progress contract

acct_ID 456 has 3 contracts: 3 cancelled contracts

acct_ID 789 has 4 contracts: 2 active contracts, 2 cancelled contracts

acct_ID 012 has 1 contract: 1 cancelled contract
```

I would like my query result to show only acct_IDs: 456 and 012 as it truly represents that they do not have "active" contracts

I'm using SQL Management Studio 2008 R2.

Comment: It would help greatly expedite an answer if you provided the subqueries to get the parts you *do* know how to obtain.

Comment: Please include your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select acct_id 
from table1 
where acct_status = "active" and 
      acct_id not in (select acct_id from table2 where contract_status = "active")

Comment: Or you could use joins. Much clearer and it's pretty much what joins were invented for.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.*
FROM Table1 A
WHERE A.acct_status = 'active'
AND NOT A.acct_id in (SELECT acct_id FROM Table2 WHERE contract_status = 'active')
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the horror of `IN` and sub-selects by utilising `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s like so:

```sql
SELECT A.*
FROM Table1 A
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 B
    ON b.acct_id = A.acct_id
    AND B.status = 'active'
WHERE b.acct_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Customer', N'U') is not null drop table #Customer

select

```
identity(int,1,1) as Customer_ID

, 'John Doe, the Ranger' as name

, '012' as Acct_ID

, 1 as Active
```

into #Customer

insert into #Customer (name, Acct_ID, Active) values ('Kermit the Frog', '789',1)

select * from #Customer

GO

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Contracts', N'U') is not null drop table #Contracts

select

```
identity(int,1,1) as Contract_ID

, 1 as Customer_ID

, '012' as Acct_ID

, 123.45 as amt

, 1 as Active
```

into #Contracts

insert into #Contracts (Customer_ID, Acct_ID, amt, active) values (1, '012', 234.56, 1)

insert into #Contracts (Customer_ID, Acct_ID, amt, active) values (2, '788', 9.56,1)

insert into #Contracts (Customer_ID, Acct_ID, amt, active) values (1, '789', 111.56, 0)

select * from #Contracts A

select *

from #Customer A

where a.Active=1

```
and (a.Acct_ID not in (select Acct_ID from #Contracts where Active=1))
```